# Anime about a swordsman who fights someone with a blade of grass

Tags: story-identification, anime

I am trying to find anything about this animation I remember watching, about a swordsman who fights someone with a blade of grass.

There were cutscenes of a blacksmith (his mentor I think) explaining the art of smithery, and he said something about how a sword cannot cut a blade of grass. Going purely off of memory I think the swordsman was fighting with a steel blade, but his opponent managed to either break his blade or send it flying out of reach. That’s when the cutscene happened, and he remembered what his mentor said about the strength of a blade of grass, which is true, if you tried to cut a blade of grass with a sword the grass would probably bend. So the swordsman picks a blade of grass and continues to fight with his opponent. In this animation, the blade of grass doesn’t bend, it just acts like a regular, extra short blade.

Take this with a grain of salt: my memory of the animation was very watercolory and reminded me a bit if Studio Ghibli, or *Avatar: The Last Airbender*. My memory on this is very patchy so I wouldn’t rely on it.

Anything would help, thank you very much!

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this and did you see it on TV? Online?

Comment: I wonder of this isnt a common storyline, but thundercats 2011 had an episode like this https://thundercats.fandom.com/wiki/The_Duelist_and_the_Drifter

Comment: A clip from The duelist and the drifter, Thundercats. The animation is animesque, like Studio Ghibli and Avatar the Last Airbender https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uBvgKtr5dlA

Comment: The scene with the sword losing against reed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t8bvlnvZnUY

Comment: Not quite what you want I guess. But, there is a scene in "Crouching Tiger, Hidden Dragon" where the master swordsman uses a reed to fight against a person with a sword.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KMZx-wF1rzw   Maybe?